# Why is $\mathbb{E}[XX] = \mathbb{E}[X^2]$?

Tags: probability

Why is $\mathbb{E}[XX] = \mathbb{E}[X^2]$?

This is always presented as obvious and without explanation, but it is not obvious to me. How does one apply the principles of a multivariate distribution involving a random variable with itself?

Comment: Well, $XX = X^2$ so ...

Comment: $XX$ is not the result of picking two random variables and multiplying their values. $X$ means a single random values, so $Y=XX$ is a random variable multiplied by itself, not by another choice of the random variable. Thus $Y$ is exactly the same random variable as $Z=X^2$.

Comment: Hm this is where the "obviousness" goes over my head. I don't interpret $E[XY]$ as taking the expectation of the product of 2 random variables, but as the expectation of their joint distribution.

Comment: @Probably, what does it mean to take the expectation of a joint distribution?

Comment: The distribution of $XX$ is the distribution of $X^2$. It's not a joint distribution though since there is only one RV.

Comment: @Probably : The expectation of the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ is $\operatorname{E}(X,Y)$, not $\operatorname{E}(XY)$.  The latter is a scalar; the former is a point in the plane. $\qquad$

Comment: It may be more appropriate to ask:  $$\text{Why is } E[XX] \neq E[X^2]$$ The former could denote the product of two separate drawings from the same distribution, while the latter $X^2$ would denote the square of a single drawing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you might be confused by the fact that one expression has two $X$'s while the other on has one $X$. You must realize that all of the $X$'s are the same thing. For example, let $X$ be $0$ or $1$ according to the flip of a coin, for tails and heads, respectively. If you flip the coin and get heads, then $X=1.$ This means that $X\cdot X=1\cdot1$, $X^2=1^2$, $X^5+3X^2-2X+8=1^5+3\cdot1^2-2\cdot1+8$, etc. You can't let $X$ be different things in different places.

If you want two distinct coin flips, you have to "have two copies of $X$", call them $X_1$ and $X_2$. Now $E[X_1X_2]\neq E[X_1^2].$

Now $X_1$ and $X_2$ have a joint distribution, but $X$ does not have a joint distribution with itself. However, a function of $X$, e.g. $g(X)=X^2$ will have a different distribution that $X$ usually. But $XX$ has the same distribution as $X^2.$

Comment: This and @Michael Hardy cleared things up. I was focusing on joint distributions when in fact it is just the product of the same copy of X. I appreciate the explanation of the subtleties as opposed to simply $XX = X^2$

Comment: Glad to be of service!